# How can I find the logic app / workflow name by workflow id?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-logic-apps

I have the workflow id of a logic app (e.g. 33ccf311e6074f668a85eff71026956b). Is there a PowerShell script which can give me the name of this logic app?

Thanks,
Rez

Answer (score 4):

Since it appears what you are referring to as "workflow id" may be a part of the access endpoint URL, you could use an Azure Resource Graph query. For example:

`az graph query -q "where type == 'microsoft.logic/workflows' and properties.accessEndpoint endswith '33ccf311e6074f668a85eff71026956b'"`